# Why does metal wire make noise but not string

Tags: noise

why when I vibrate metal string it make noise but when I vibrate string it no make noise?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This clearly isn't the case in acoustic guitars that can have non-metallic strings.